# Base class referenced in stack trace line?

Tags: java, eclipse, overriding, stack-trace, superclass

when debugging java code, in the stack trace, I noticed that something in the following

`ToyotaCar(AbstractCar).handle()` line: 40

It looks like the class in the brace is the base class. Will eclipse always show the base class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you invoke a method of a base class, the stack line will show both the base class (where the method is defined) and the class of the object that invoked such method.

I assume here that you did something like

```
ToyotaCar car = new ToyotaCar();
car.handle();
```

where `ToyotaCar` does not override the `handle()` method. The stack trace notifies you that your call to `handle()` is not served by the actual `ToyotaCar`, but by `AbstractCar`. Yet, you invoked it on a `ToyotaCar` object.

By itself, this notation for a stack line might seem excessive if you don't override base class methods. Consider, however, the case where you want to override the `handle()` method, but still need to call `handle()` on `AbstractCar`. You will need to issue a

```
super.handle();
```

inside `ToyotaCar.handle()`. When calling the `handle()` method on a `ToyotaCar` object, you will first call it as a `ToyotaCar` and then as an `AbstractCar`. The two stack lines will unambiguously allow you to tell one call from the other.